# It is true that, during the first years of professional football, teams used to play with only 2 defenders and 5 forwards?

Tags: football, history, tactics

I've heard many times that, in the past (I don't know exactly when, but It may be around 1930 and 1950 decades) football teams used to align using 2-3-5 formation.

I know that tactics used to be less defensive at those times, and it used to be more goals, but I guess if this were completely true, an we interpreter 2-3-5 as 2 defenders, 3 midfields and 5 forwards in the same sense we refer to those positions today, it should have been dozens of goals per match.

I also rembember reading a quote from some old player saying that I was an exaggeration, and that just the idea of 5 forwards against 2 defenders is ridiculous.

Can anybody explain how football tactics worked at those times?

Comment: Keep in mind that before the 1930s, the offside rule was a lot different - you needed to be farther than the goal line than (or level with) the third last opponent, not the second last opponent. This made holding a line with less defenders much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YES** but it was not a rule

[This site](http://footballspeak.com/post/2012/04/07/Innovate.aspx) confirm that, in the early 1900s, tactics were more offensive than now.

Also [this source](http://www.football-bible.com/soccer-info/old-football-formations.html) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_%28association_football%29) confirm that the old off side rules permits to play with those tactics.

I think you can find a lot of exhaustive info on the posted links, so I prefer to do not add more.

Comment: Yes. That explains why those tactics were used before 1925, which is the year when the off-side rule changed. But there are famous later teams which used 5 forwards. I known some argentinian teams examples, like River Plate's La Máquina in the 40's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_M%C3%A1quina

Comment: Now that I read yout Football Bible source, I think that those 40's teams probably used the 3-2-2-3 MW tactic, which also has 5 forwards, but it's more balanced.

Comment: Some of those tactics numberings are confusing. For example, Victorio Pozzo's Il metodo is refered as 2-3-2-3, but two of the midfielders were responsible of mark the opponent's wingers! Makes much more sense to call them defenders instead of midfielders. That way it would be 4-1-2-3