# Why was the 1-1-8 formation popular in 19th Century football?

Tags: football, history, formations

Today I learned that 1-1-8 is one of the oldest football formations. It was widespread in 19th century. Why this unusual formation was so popular?

Comment: Closely related: [It is true that, during the first years of professional football, teams used to play with only 2 defenders and 5 forwards?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/it-is-true-that-during-the-first-years-of-professional-football-teams-used-to). The game has become more defensive over the years, starting with extreme formations like the 1-1-8 and moving through 2-3-5 to something like today's 4-4-2.

Answer (score 2):

When you say 19th century, you probably mean after 1863, when association football and rugby football split up, [The FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Football_Association) was formed and later ball handling, shin-kicking, tripping and holding an opponent were disallowed.

In FIFA article [History of Football - The Global Growth](https://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/who-we-are/the-game/global-growth.html), these extreme formations are explained with the fact that despite splitting up with rugby football and change of rules, the game tactics were still similar.

> When Scotland played England in Glasgow on 30 November 1872, [...]
>   Both teams employed what might today be considered rather attacking
>   formations - Scotland (2-2-6), England (1-1-8) - but back then the
>   game still retained many of the mob-football characteristics of
>   kicking and rushing and, in tactics at least, probably more closely
>   resembled modern-day rugby than football.

[image: England - Scotland]

The poster from that match. Source: [The FA](http://www.thefa.com/about-football-association/what-we-do/history)